# Check field in obj

Tags: javascript

Good day. 
I've got

```
array a  = [
            {a:1, value: 2},
            {a:2, value: 2},
            {a:3, value: 2}
           ]
```

How I can check if all objects got same value `return true` if in one object I got different value `return false.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is using `new Set()` to get all the unique values. If the unique value is only one, it means all values are the same.

```js
let a  = [{a:1, value: 2},{a:2, value: 2},{a:3, value: 2}];
let result = [...new Set(a.map(o => o.value))].length === 1;

console.log(result);
```

---

To reduce overhead, as per suggested by Nina, you can:

```js
let a  = [{a:1, value: 2},{a:2, value: 2},{a:3, value: 2}];
let result = new Set(a.map(o => o.value)).size === 1;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: nice idea, but with a bit of overhead. you could use `size` property of `Set`: `let result = new Set(a.map(o => o.value)).size === 1;`

Comment: Yeah.. Better idea. Thanks @NinaScholz

Comment: it still needs to iterate all elements, twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the first value against all others.

```js
var array = [{ a: 1, value: 2 }, { a: 2, value: 2 }, { a: 3, value: 2 }],
    result = array.every(({ value }, _, a) => a[0].value === value);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is build int function `every`. You pass a predicate into it and if every item satisfied predicate - returns `true`, else - `false`.

```js
const arr  = [{a:1, value: 2},{a:2, value: 2},{a:3, value: 2}];
const result = arr.every(item => item.value === 2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I dont' know what the value equal. They could be different.

Comment: So pass your value instead of `2`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple logic using `for` to know if the `value` matches or not. Also, create a reusable function `isMatch(arr)` so that it can be reused for multiple array having same structure.

```js
function isMatch(arr){
  var val = arr[0].value;
  var match = true;
  for(var i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(val !== arr[i].value){
      match = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return match;
}
var a  = [{a:1, value: 2},{a:2, value: 2},{a:3, value: 2}];
console.log(isMatch(a));

a  = [{a:1, value: 2},{a:2, value: 3},{a:3, value: 2}];
console.log(isMatch(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

People recommend using `every`, but I would recommend using `some` : `every` iterates over all items of the array, while `some` stops at the item when the predicate is false. In your example, this doesn't change much, but on large sets, it can improve performances.

try something like this :

```js
const arr = [{a:1, value: 2}, {a:2, value: 2}, {a:3, value: 2}];

const value = arr[0].value;
const areEqual = arr.some(arrItem => arrItem.value === value);

console.log('are all equal : ', areEqual);
```

Answer (score 0):

For my question help this answer

```
var answer = new Set(a.map(({value}) => value)).size === 1;
```